# Why can't get a GWT UI Binder template to use a ClientBundle from my project

Tags: gwt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ui:UiBinder SYSTEM "http://dl.google.com/gwt/DTD/xhtml.ent">
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
    xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

    <ui:with field='res' type='com.myproject.resources.Resources'/>

    <ui:style>
        .panel {
            background-color: ivory;
        }
    </ui:style>

    <g:FlowPanel styleName='{style.panel}'>
        <g:Image url='{res.logo}'/>
        <g:VerticalPanel>
            <g:PushButton text="My Button" ui:field="myButton"></g:PushButton>
        </g:VerticalPanel>
    </g:FlowPanel>
</ui:UiBinder>
```

I have a resources class

```
public interface  Resources extends ClientBundle {
      public static final Resources INSTANCE =  GWT.create(Resources.class);

      @Source("logo.png")
      ImageResource logo();


}
```

I don't get any errors in the GWT XML editor, however, GWT designer will not load. An When I run it I get an Exception also.

```
onModuleLoad() threw an exception
Exception while loading module com.myproject.client.MyProject. See Development Mode for details.

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.myproject.client.ClientFactory' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:97)
    at com.myproject.client.MyProject.onModuleLoad(MyProject.java:42)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:503)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you try to compile your gwt project and see if you get an error ?

Comment: This is what I am getting `[ERROR] No such type com.myproject.resources.Resources Element <ui:with field='res' type='com.myproject.resources.Resources'> (:7)`, however the class does exist

Comment: The problem is that GWT looks by default into your ``client`` and ``shared`` folder (configureable in the GWT module xml) for sources. I guess ``com.myproject.resources.Resources`` can't be seen from the GWT compiler. So move the Resources package into ``com.myproject.client.resources.Resources``

Comment: I added `<source path='resources'/>` to the xml file and it started working.  All the png files are already in `com.myproject.client.resources.Resources`, I still don't understand why this worked or why i needed to do it.

Comment: Because the GWT compiler needs access to the sources in order to create the javascript output files. Because GWT projects can be mixed with server side code by default GWT only looks into the ``client`` and ``shared`` folder. Any resource which is not in those folders won't be seen by the GWT compiler. Alternatively as you did you can add a source path to your Module

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell if it's you issue or not, but your code should be:

```
<g:Image resource='{res.logo}'/>
```

(i.e. `resource`, not `url`)

Comment: oh yeah, that was me mucking around with it.  I tried that but am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this inherits tag in your gwt.xml file, it is required when using ClientBundle:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.resources.Resources" />
```

Comment: It is according to the GWT doc: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle

Comment: It's already inherited transitively by `com.google.gwt.user.User` (which it self is transitively inherited by `com.google.gwt.uibinder.UiBinder`). It's only required if you use neither `User` nor `UiBinder` (or another module that inherits it too)